# converting 8/17/2003 to boost::gregorian::date

Tags: c++, date, boost

I am attempting to convert `8/17/2003` to `boot::gregorian::date` using the following code

```
std::string test = "08/17/2013";
date d(from_simple_string(test));
```

However I get an unhandled exception any suggestion on how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the boost examples:

```
// The following date is in ISO 8601 extended format (CCYY-MM-DD)
std::string s("2001-10-9"); //2001-October-09
date d(from_simple_string(s));
std::cout << to_simple_string(d) << std::endl;
```

You have the format incorrect.

Comment: Marked as answer after timer